# Elasticsearch parallel scroll reads for reindexing

Tags: elasticsearch, parallel-processing, apache-storm

Trying to fully process an index into another (doing ETL in between) via Storm.

I am opening several parallel scrolls, each targetting a subset of the source index using query constraints. Can't really leverage routing -- the source index has routing on a random key, and the point of this application is partly to change the physical configuration of a full index). Is this a valid approach?

Workers essentially create mutually exclusive queries that together cover the entire index. By reading from them in parallel, performing transformations and then writing in bulk to the target, I am aiming at maximum throughput, but I would much appreciate any insights or recommendations. I am not set on using Storm -- but I do need a parallel framework to perform arbitrary transformations on the data.

As far as I know, I don't believe this is something a ES plugin can/should do. A river implementation sounds more reasonable, but I am puzzled as to why a ES-to-ES river doesn't already exist -- is it not a reasonable approach? Many thanks.